# SonarQube in angular project - Line 2 of report refers to a file with an unknown language

Tags: angular, sonarqube

I have configured angular project for SonarQube. But it gives exception

ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Error during parsing of generic test execution report '/Users/username/abc-fe/reports/ut_report.xml'. Look at the SonarQube documentation to know the expected XML format.
ERROR: Caused by: Line 2 of report refers to a file with an unknown language: src/app/requests/detail/abc/abc.component.spec.ts
ERROR:

Following is the part of report.xml

```
<testExecutions version="1">
  <file path="src/app/requests/detail/abc/abc.component.spec.ts">
    <testCase name="ViewDocumentComponent should create" duration="238"/>
  </file>
  <file path="src/app/shared/alert/zyx.component.spec.ts">
    <testCase name="AlertPopUpModalComponent should create" duration="13"/>
  </file>
</testExecutions>
```

Following are the properties for sonar.properties

```
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**, src/assets/styles/**
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths= coverage/lcov.info,
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths= reports/report.xml
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across the same problem.

At the moment this [community post](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/generictestexecutionreport-limited-to-known-languages/5785/7) only refers to an open [issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-12015#) at sonar.
The short summary is: if you have unknown languages in your coverage files you have a problem, because this issue is still open.

Edit: I found a workaround, which works for me.
I'm already using [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) to generate different outputs. It has an exclude flag, where specific files can be omitted from the result.

So the relevant flags would be: "-reporttypes:SonarQube", to generate a coverage file for SonarQube and "-filefilters:-*.spec.ts" to exclude the files from this report. The then generated coverage report can then consumed by sonarqube with "/d:sonar.coverageReportPaths=SonarQube.xml".

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)